# How to use checkbox in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a code of checkbox below in ruby on rails:

```
<%= check_box(:Monday,{:id => "Monday",:value => "Monday"}) %>
```

But, it shows only the checkbox but not shows its text i.e "Monday".

So what should I do to display the text of checkbox, kindly suggest me, waiting for reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this?

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

Either you use the check_box_tag or the f.check_box inside a form builder, plus you have to add a label to display it. 
The construct you are using just generate the `<input type="checkbox" value="something" />` and not the label, that you have to add, just like text or with a `<%= label_tag 'whatever' %>`.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do is

```
<%= check_box_tag "Monday", 'yes', id:"monday" %> Monday
```

or u can do this also

```
 <%= check_box_tag "Monday", "yes" %>
 <%= label_tag "Monday" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
<%= check_box :monday, {:class => "anyclass", :style => "anystyle"}, "monday" %>
```

Comment: What's about the comment I cannot get u @Erik

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use a label](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box):

```
<%= form_tag your_path do %>
    <%= label "Day" %>
    <%= check_box "Monday", "yes" %>
<% end %>
```